# Is there any reason not to use a new Kotlin version of a library in a Java project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx

I created a new app on android studio 4.1.1 and put some libraries from androidx. Some of these libraries have a new version that uses the Kotlin language. For example, `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2` has a new version with kotlin.

Is it problem (or a good practice) to mix Java and Kotlin libraries in the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issue mixing Java and Kotlin libraries: Kotlin has excellent interoperability with Java code.

Adding Kotlin libraries to a project will increase your binary size somewhat by including the Kotlin standard library, so you should make sure to [shrink your code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-code) (which you should be doing regardless of whether you use Kotlin) to minimize the impact on binary size.